# Minimize distance from a point to a parabola

Tags: calculus

> Find the point on the parabola $$y^2=3x$$ that is closest to the point $(1,7)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point on that parabola can be parametrized as $(\frac{y^2}{3},y)$. Now find the distance between $(\frac{y^2}{3},y)$ and $(1,7)$ and minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equation of $\displaystyle  y^2=3x=4\cdot\frac34x$ is $\displaystyle \left(\frac34t^2,2\cdot\frac34t\right)=\left(\frac{3t^2}4,\frac{3t}2\right)$ or $(3u^2,3u)$ putting $t=3u$ for the ease of calculation

So, we need to minimize $\displaystyle \left(1-3u^2\right)^2+\left(7-3u\right)^2$ which is a function of $u$